# Calling an element of a string as a char in C++

Tags: c++, string, user-interface, char

This is for use in a GUI using C++ and FLTK.

Say I have a `string x = "ABCDEFG"` and an array of boxes `y[7]`.

I'd want to put one of those letters as the label on a box using a for loop such as:

```
for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {   
  y[i] = new Fl_Box(120+31*i,40,30,30,"A");
}
```

but rather than "A" on all of them, of course I'd want "A" on `y[0]`, "B" on `y[1]`, "C" on `y[2]`, etc - with the letter called from the string as the element `x[i]`.

I tried simply using `x[0]`, etc and found that it needed a conversion to char.

I then tried `&x[0]` and found it just prints the whole string on each of them as its a const char.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `FL_Box` expects a C-string style (null terminated), consider using a temporary value.

```
std::string(x[i], 1).c_str()
```

This is similar to passing

```
char temp[2] = { 0 };
temp[0] = x[i];
```

and passing `temp`.

Comment: As with the first method, passing temps results in "G" on each box due to the const char. How can I get round this?

Comment: The `const char` isn't the reason why; that explanation doesn't make sense. Are you sure that you are not adding the same instance of the `FL_Box` instead?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `substr()` method of `std::string` like:

```
for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {   
  y[i] = new Fl_Box(120+31*i,40,30,30, x.substr(i, 1).c_str());
}
```

Here is the signature of `substr()`:

```
string substr (size_t pos = 0, size_t len = npos) const;
```

Here is a quick test program an its output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::string x = "ABCDEFG";
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        printf("i(%d) c(%s)\n", i, x.substr(i, 1).c_str());
    }
    return 0;
}

# ./a.out
i(0) c(A)
i(1) c(B)
i(2) c(C)
i(3) c(D)
i(4) c(E)
i(5) c(F)
i(6) c(G)
```

Comment: `FL_Box` takes a `const char*` as last parameter so you'll want this to be `x.substr(i, 1).c_str()`.

Comment: Thanks for responses. This leads to a "G" for each of the boxes since it passes a const char. Is there a way round this?

Comment: It works fine in command line, but it doesn't output correctly with Fl_Box - That's where the problem lies now.